# How to test if an xml tag is 3 char long and uppercase with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform an XML file with XSL and I need to test if a tag is 3 character long and uppercase. 
The XML file I am trying to transform (and I have no control over the format of this) looks like this:

```
<RECORD>
   <AAA>
       <c01>1</c01>
       <c02>2</c02>
   </AAA>
   <BBB>
       <c01>3</c01>
       <c02>4</c02>
   </BBB>
</RECORD>
```

And I need to separate the AAA and BBB tags with ":" so I get something like

```
AAA:1+2;BBB:3+4;
```

However, AAA and BBB can be practically any 3 letter combination.
Otherwise I could have done something like this.

```
<xsl:param name="X">AAA:BBB:CCC</xsl:param>
<xsl:for-each select="//*[contains($X, substring(local-name(), 1, 3))]">
```

I have found xsl functions uppercase and lowercase, but nothing to test the case in a simple way. Does anyone know how to achieve this, without making it too complicated?

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0? If not, is it sufficient to test that the name characters are in the range of A-Z? --- Your second question is not clear: you show only one element in each group, so the separation is trivial. Can there be more than one?

Comment: I'm using XSLT 1.0, but might possibly be able to use 2.0. It is only the 3 letter tag that I have problems to match, because I don't know what the letters will be. Only that there are 3 uppercase letters. I can match the other elements, because they all start with the character "c".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use XSLT 2.0, you can use the `matches` function to make use of regular expressions

```
 <xsl:for-each select="//*[matches(local-name(), '^[A-Z]{3}$')]">
```

In XSLT 1.0, it is a little more work, but you could do something like this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="//*[string-length(local-name()) = 3 and translate(local-name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '') = '']">
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!